# VBA to merge cells in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, vba

I have a excel sheet like below. Consider the sno column as Excel numbering.
So all the columns except DateTime are merged. I want to Merge the DateTime cells and want to delete the empty records. I tried a few formulas with no success. Is this possible

I tried below formula but its giving weird results becoz of datetime values i think.

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$<ENDROW>,(B1-1)*2+1,1)&" "&INDEX($A$1:$A$<ENDROW>,(B1-1)*2+2,1)
```

**I have this:**

```
╔═════╦════════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
║ sno ║ Action ║ DateTime ║ User ID ║    Name     ║
╠═════╬════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
║   1 ║ INSERT ║ 8-Nov-13 ║ childsk ║ Keri Childs ║
║   2 ║        ║ 16:06:43 ║         ║             ║
║   3 ║ INSERT ║ 8-Nov-13 ║ childsk ║ Keri Childs ║
║   4 ║        ║ 16:04:27 ║         ║             ║
╚═════╩════════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
```

**Expected Output:**

```
╔═════╦════════╦═══════════════════╦═════════╦═════════════╗
║ sno ║ Action ║     DateTime      ║ User ID ║    Name     ║
╠═════╬════════╬═══════════════════╬═════════╬═════════════╣
║   1 ║ INSERT ║ 8-Nov-13 16:06:43 ║ childsk ║ Keri Childs ║
║   2 ║ INSERT ║ 8-Nov-13 16:04:27 ║ childsk ║ Keri Childs ║
╚═════╩════════╩═══════════════════╩═════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: Robert, did you find anything posted here useful? If so, pls rate it.

Answer (score 0):

You have two tasks to perform.

1. To merge date and time into a single cell. This is simply done by (Cell C1 contains the formula (as text) that is used in B1.)
   [image]

   and formatting B1 as Custom -> d-mmm-yy hh:mm:ss.

   Then you can copy the results (as values) and format to a destination column.
2. Remove extra rows. You can use the code below (make sure you change the number of repetitions from 10 to whatever you need).

.

```
Sub del_skip_rows_repeat_caller()
    Call del_skip_rows_repeat(1, 10)
End Sub
Sub del_skip_rows_repeat(nrows As Integer, nrep As Integer)
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To nrep
      Call del_skip_rows(nrows)
    Next i
End Sub
Sub del_skip_rows(nrows As Integer)
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = Range(Selection, Selection.Offset(nrows - 1, 0)).EntireRow
    'rng.Select
    rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Set rng = Selection.Offset(1, 0).Cells(1, 1)
    rng.Select
End Sub
```